# AngularJS change <li> element tags based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a list in which each list element can have different styles. Simple `HTML` looks like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="[link]">One</a></li>
<li><a href="[link]">Two</a></li>
```

When the user clicks `two`then I want the active element to move to that list item. I have tried the following solution.

```
// In my menu controller

// Determines which link that should be active
$scope.activeLinkID = 0;

// Associative array with link names and paths
$scope.linkArray = {};

// Index 0 = linkName, index 1 = linkPath
$scope.linkArray[0] = ["One", "#/link/one"]
$scope.linkArray[1] = ["Two", "#/link/two"]
[...]
```

I have tried to display this in my view like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="(linkIndex, link) in linkArray | orderBy:linkIndex"><a href="{{link[1]}}">{{link[0]}}</a></li>
```

But I got stuck when trying to add elements into my `<li>` tag. The condition would be `activeLinkID == linkIndex` then add class="active".

I'm not sure which is the best way to achive this using `AngularJS`. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You should definitely check out the ngClass directive for changing classes based on a condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller

```
$scope.selectedIndex = -1;
$scope.links = [
  ["One", "#/link/one"],
  ["Two", "#/link/two"]
];
```

In your view

```
<li ng-repeat="link in link" 
    ng-class="{'active': $parent.selectedIndex == $index}">
      <a ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex = $index">{{link[0]}}</a>
</li>
```

Here's a working demo  http://jsbin.com/exafUmuq/2/edit?html,js,output

It seems like you're trying to accomplish something that [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) was built to solve. You should take some time to learn about it, it will save you lots of headaches.

Great video on ui-router can be found here
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router

Comment: Thanks, got it to work. ui-router do look like something I should use. Will read more about it. One side-question.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a div the `ng` function inside your div like this

```
<div> <li ng-repeat="(linkIndex, link) in linkArray | orderBy:linkIndex"><a href="{{link[1]}}">{{link[0]}}</a></li></div>
```

See if that works. Did for me